# From QGIS to Google Maps coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, epsg, maps, google

I try to convert QGIS coordinates to Google Maps coordinates.

I use this form:

```
geom_to_wkt( transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:25832', 'EPSG:4326' ) )
```

I getting the coordinate like this:

```
 Point (12.30982365 55.73210873)
```

If I copy this coordinates into Google Maps I'm ending up in the middle of the Indian Ocean, so I need to get them turned around so it simple to copy/paste to Google Maps.

```
Point (55.73210873 12.30982365)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Some more information about your data (csv, shape, kml?) and the goal you want to achieve by pasting them into Maps would be useful.

Comment: @Erik it's shape file and only points. I use Qgis2Web to export a map to our technicans in the field. We also have extern people who helps us, so I need the coordinates so they can copy/paste them to Google Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for could be achieved with the following expression in the Field calculator. Just create a corresponding text field beforehand.

```py
y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:25832','EPSG:4326')) || ', '|| x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:25832','EPSG:4326'))
```

Additionally, you may be interested in alternative solutions:

1. QGIS 2: a plugin [Swap XY](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/swapXY/)
2. QGIS 3: a native geoalgorithm `"Swap x/y coordinate values"`.

If you want to wrap the coordinates-set in WKT as the point then use this expression:

```py
geom_to_wkt(make_point(y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:25832','EPSG:4326')),
                       x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:25832','EPSG:4326' ))))
```

---

**References:**

- [Is there a way to use a spatial query to invert X and Y coordinates in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236345/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-spatial-query-to-invert-x-and-y-coordinates-in-qgis)